# Не получается принять http запрос с помощью spring mvc

Tags: java, spring-mvc

написал программу для принятия get запроса с помощью спринг мвс(версия 5.2.2), но при отправки запроса по адресу выдает ошибку 404. Сервер даже не вызывает метод тест, не знаю в чем причина.

код программы

```
@Controller
public class main {

    @RequestMapping(value="/hello", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void test(){
        System.out.println("testing");
    }
}
```

maven

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Заранее спасибо

web-inf/lib
  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Весь код https://github.com/artem-kurilko/MVC-controller

Comment: как и куда отправляете GET?

Comment: отправляю с помощью постмана на адрес http://localhost:8040/hello

Comment: порт при запуску точно 8040?

Comment: да уверен, отправлял без /hello возвращало html страницу

Comment: можете вывод(лог) при запуске(поднятии) приложения привести

Comment: @АртёмКурилко 1 - у вас точно порт `8040`? обычно по умолчанию `8080`.

Comment: 2 - Вы создавали страницу "test"?

Comment: поставьте аннотацию `@RestController` вместо `@Controller`

Comment: логи об ошибке пусты, да стандартный 8080, но у меня развернуты ещё сервисы поэтому пришлось поменять, есть только index.jsp больше ничего

Comment: на счет @restcontroller все равно выбивает ошибку

Comment: Немного облегчим задачу всем, вы хотите выводить `index.jsp`-страницу на экран или `JSON / Plain text`? От это будет зависеть код страницы)

Comment: мне нужно сначала чтобы сервер видел запрос, остальное неважно, может любую строку выводить типо "получил"

Comment: сейчас у вас void, т.е. клиенту никакой полезной нагрузки...даже в случае успешного отрабатывания метода, на клиенте вы ничего не увидите, увидите только `testing` в выводе сервера

Comment: да знаю, мне нужно чтобы сервер видел запросы, он не видит, вывод самого метода меня пока не интересует главное чтобы сработало

Comment: Как насчет написания имени класса с большой буквы, и приписки слова контроллер к имени класса? Просто для культуры кода

Comment: слово контроллер там есть

Comment: "public class MainController" - по-хорошему класс должен называться вот так. советую прочитать общепринятые нормы именования классов

Comment: ааа, понял, да так следовало написать

Comment: и вообще, по умолчанию, веб-сервисы слушают порт 8080; если у вас не прописано иначе в настройках. "просто так" listener не будет обращаться к 8040-порту.

Comment: Каким образом вы запускаете приложение? Класса для запуска не вижу; разворачиваете ли вы это в томкате?

Comment: да, использую томкат

Comment: 1) попробуйте принудительно задать мэппинг в web.xml
2) проверьте номер порта, к которому вы пытаетесь обратиться
3) проверьте настройки томката

Comment: не знаю как указать имя контроллера, там есть имя сервлета но это ведь не сервлет, так как нет аннотации webservlet, остальное впорядке

Comment: вы слишком рано полезли в изучение MVC, не разобравшись в базе. мой совет - вернуться к теории

Comment: У каждого свой путь обучения @MaksimRybalkin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте данный вариант

```java
@Controller
public class main {

    @GetMapping("/hello") 
    public String test(){
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.setViewName("index");
        return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

Comment: все равно выбивает ошибку

Comment: @АртёмКурилко можете закинуть проект в гит?

Comment: да, через пару минут скину

Comment: https://github.com/artem-kurilko/MVC-controller